# how to change width or height only video tag and same size with poster?

Tags: html, css

How to make a video tag the same size as a poster?

```
<div class="col-6">
 <div class=".fullscreen-bg__video my-2 ">
     <video  width="100%"  height="100%" controlslist="nodownload"  poster="./img/4444a.jpg" 
       controls="true"  muted>
           <source type="video/mp4" src="./img/6f6035efab042985c4494cc976f23247.mp4">
            <span>dosent't support</span>
    </video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS

```
.postr{
object-fit: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<video class="postr" width="100%"  height="100%"
controlslist="nodownload" poster="./img/4444a.jpg" controls="true" muted>
```

If that doesn't work then then try `object:fill`